# Formatted APFS in Mojave shows file format in system report as MS-DOS

Tags: ssd

just fitted an ssd to my Mac Pro 5.1 Mojave enabled, working ok but when I looked at the system report it says the file system is ms-dos, is this a problem? the only option I had for formatting the ssd in disk utility was APFS which I chose

[image: System report]

Thanks Ted

Comment: Your disk *is* formatted in APFS, but only mostly. There's also a small (209.7 MB), hidden volume in FAT format that's used for things like firmware updates. The FAT volume is disk0s1, the APFS container is disk0s2.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine as the **EFI** volume is supposed to be formatted **MS-DOS FAT32**, and as you can see your **disk0s2** volume is as should be **Apple_APFS**.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. In my ignorance I thought it was formatted for Windows, that's put my mind at rest

  kind Regards 

  Ted

Comment: @Ted Stewart, Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)